# Sharing code logic between php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website that does some complex math on the server side (php) and on the client side (javascript). The math is identical on both sides, and the code was manually translated between the languages. The problem is in code maintenance: one always needs to update and validate both sides when doing a modification. Is there a way to have to maintain only one side, and have the other side reflect the changes?

Any other options? Are there automatic code translaters that could auto-generate some core files?

One solution not considered si to do ajax requests to the server instead of doing the math client-side. This has been rejected due to the response time being too long.

Comment: Should perhaps be using Node on the server side then instead of PHP :-)

Comment: can you get more specific on the logic that needs to be done on client/server that is the same?

Comment: @depperm it's only "basic" math. Long equations with basic operations, sin, cos, exponents. While loops to perform some iterative processes until the data converges.

Comment: You can install a JS runtime on the server, then you’ll only have the JavaScript version to worry about.

Comment: Looks like a valid option, will try. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an option to do all the maths client-side only, and just send the results to the server? Or is it critical that the server can validate the same calculation without relying on what the client-side tells it?

Comment: @ADyson the client side cannot be trusted and the math must be checked by the server

Comment: Ok. In that case yes, I would suggest that if you only want to write the logic once, you'd better use JavaScript for both client- and server-side code, then you can try to share the modules / functions between them. There is no tool which can automatically convert between PHP and JS.